# Enable JSX folding in web-mode

Tags: web-mode, javascript

I'm using `web-mode` to edit `jsx` files and I'm wondering what minor-mode can I use to add folding support. Is there anything out there that works?

Thanks

Comment: What have you already tired?

Comment: Vim and Sublime and they both work :) Just sayin'

Comment: Well, for example, [`vimish-fold`](https://github.com/mrkkrp/vimish-fold) should be language agnostic. [`origami`](https://github.com/gregsexton/origami.el) may also work with its indentation based parser.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's an old question, I'll share my setup for anyone still looking for ways to do this.

I use built-in `hideshow` package with additional configuration for handling HTML tags.

```
(use-package hideshow
  :diminish hs-minor-mode
  :config
  (add-to-list 'hs-special-modes-alist
               '(web-mode
                 "<!--\\|<[^/>]*[^/]>"
                 "-->\\|</[^/>]*[^/]>"
                 "<!--"
                 web-mode-forward-sexp
                 nil)))
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not quite a full answer (unless you're O. K. with ditching web-mode which I would think is less than ideal) but Hideshow Minor Mode will, technically, get the job done for you.

If you enable it (with `(hs-minor-mode t)`), running the function `hs-hide-block` while the cursor is within a pair of curly braces will fold that block.

The one snag in all of this – from the perspective of web development in Emacs – is that Web Mode won't allow you to enable Hideshow Minor Mode while it (Web Mode) is in use. An ideal answer will allow find someway to enable the feature while keeping Web Mode present and fully functional.

Comment: Seems I spoke somewhat too soon – the error is not, per se, with Web Mode itself (assuming that not initializing particular variables were not a deliberate choice) but with the variables `comment-start` and `comment-end` being `nil`. With those not having a string value of some sort, starting `hs-minor-mode` will fail.

Comment: As far as I can tell `web-mode` is the mode to use with jsx. Isn't it? I mean I wouldn't want to loose other features just to get folding.

Comment: @Cezar perhaps [`js2-jsx-mode`](https://github.com/mooz/js2-mode/blob/master/js2-mode.el#L63)?

Comment: @Cezar Agreed; plus, Web Mode is super helpful when dealing with anything web related, I find. Take a look at the comment I left right above yours – the problem actually isn't with Web Mode but the variables `comment-start` and `comment-end` not being set to anything other than `nil`. Something I put in my .emacs file was

`(defun func-name-of-choice ()
    (let ((ext (file-name-extension (buffer-name))))
        (cond

Comment: @Cezar (ignoring the beginning of the code in that last comment:) `(defun func-name-of-choice ()  (let ((ext (file-name-extension (buffer-name)))) (cond ((string-equal ext "css") (setq-local comment-start "/* ") (setq-local comment-end " */")) ((string-equal ext "js") (setq-local comment-start "// ") (setq-local comment-end "")) ((or  (string-equal ext "html") (string-equal ext "xml")) (setq-local comment-start "<!-- ") (setq-local comment-end " -->")))) (hs-minor-mode t))` That, when entering web mode, determines what the file ext. is and sets comments appropriately and enters HS Minor Mode.

Comment: Just note that I can not initialize ```comment-start``` and ```comment-end``` because web-mode need to deal with all the comment formats. Perhaps ```hs-minor-mode``` should take this into account.

Comment: @fxbois I found that it didn't make a difference; I initialized both and `web-mode` handled them just as it usually does. I found that to be the case for other modes as well. While there are particular instances where it will effect (in ways that were so arbitrary that I don't remember them and they didn't disrupt my work flow), it's mostly not an issue. I agree it's bad design but it won't get in your way of getting work done.

Comment: @Jaft maybe i do not understand your comment. Do you advice to initialize comment-start and comment-end to a fixed value ?

Comment: @fxbois Yes, though only in particular instances. The function I put above figures out the file extension of the current file and then sets those variables based off of that; lastly, you add the function to the `web-mode-hook` so it won't be set for just any files. Since the whole advantage of `web-mode` is the ability to work with, say, HTML, CSS, and JavaScript all in the same file, I had wondered if setting those variables would disallow proper commenting but, at least, `M-;` worked fine and was able to figure out which you were working with. I didn't test anything else (largely because I

Comment: @fxbois don't use any other commenting functions), admittedly, but it didn't seem to make any difference. The function I provided only sets the `comment-start` and `comment-end` variables for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files so you're not changing it for every instance and I don't seem to see much change in anything (other than the newly acquired ability to actually use `hs-minor-mode` with `web-mode`). Hopefully that's clearer; sorry about the previous confusion.

Comment: Folding JSX won't be related to braces, it will be likely used to fold instances of components, which are almost XML syntax. Since `web-mode` supports many languages in a single buffer, the problem becomes non-trivial as someone might want to be able to have different kinds of text objects folded in the same buffer.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10: literally just use both – I do all the time and it works just fine. Write a function that calls `(ignore-errors (web-mode-fold-or-unfold)) (hs-hide-block)` and it'll handle both XML and JavaScript/CSS. Then bind it to whatever key your heart desires.